# Javascript Q&A Quiz not working

Tags: javascript, html, testing

here is my code. I want to make a javascript based quiz for mcqs. There is a problem while making the verify() function. How to select the user selected option and then match it with the correct answer of that question and tell the status? Thanks

```js
function verify() {
  var correct = 1;
  var selected = 0;
  if (getElementByID.r1) selected = 1;

  if (selected == correct) window.alert("You are right");
  else window.alert("You WRong!!!");

}
```

```html
<img src="//placekitten.com/g/50/50" alt="x" />
<br><br><br>
<input type="radio" id=r1 /><strong>1. </strong>
<p id=ans1>This is cloud</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" id=r2 /><strong>2. </strong>
<p id=ans2>This is hat</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" id=r3 /><strong>3. </strong>
<p id=ans3>This is rough</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" id=r4 /><strong>4. </strong>
<p id=ans4>This is none</p>
<br />

<input type="button" onclick=verify(); value="send" />
<input type="button" onclick=reveal(); value="Reveal Solution" />
```

Comment: Start with console opened.... and check for errors.

Comment: im using netbeans. its all compile, run buttons are disabled.

Comment: What do you expect `getElementByID.r1` to do?

Comment: if the user selects the radio button which id is r1, then it should be "TRUE".

Comment: How do you compile javascript code, exactly? Also, legal code =/= working code, run it.

Answer (score 1):

With radio buttons, you want them all to have the same `name`.  That way when you check one, the others will be unchecked.

Also, `getElementByID.r1` doesn't do anything.  `getElementById` (note the capitalization) is a *property* of `document` and is a *function*.

```
document.getElementById('r1')
```

Then, with radio buttons, you use the `.checked` property to see if it was checked or not.

```
if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) selected = 1;
```

Here's an updated demo:

```js
function verify() {
  var correct = 1;
  var selected = 0;
  if (document.getElementById('r1').checked) selected = 1;

  if (selected == correct) window.alert("You are right");
  else window.alert("You WRong!!!");

}
```

```html
<img src="//placekitten.com/g/50/50" alt="x" />
<br><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id=r1 /><strong>1. </strong>
<p id=ans1>This is cloud</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id=r2 /><strong>2. </strong>
<p id=ans2>This is hat</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id=r3 /><strong>3. </strong>
<p id=ans3>This is rough</p>
<br />
<input type="radio" name="quiz" id=r4 /><strong>4. </strong>
<p id=ans4>This is none</p>
<br />

<input type="button" onclick=verify(); value="send" />
<input type="button" onclick=reveal(); value="Reveal Solution" />
```